# How to disable QML ListView highlighting

Tags: qt, qml

[highlighting on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c5IM.jpg)

I want to disable this highlighting that appears on delegate hovering. I've already tried to set interactive: false and transparent rect for "highlight" property. Image in link.
Code:

```
                    ListView {
                    id: friendsListView
                    anchors.top: parent
                    width: parent.width
                    height: friendsModel.count *
                            ((stl.setsCmnTxtHght + stl.setsCmnBtnHght) * 2 + stl.setsCmnVertSpace * 3 + stl.setsCmnVertSpace);
                    interactive: false

                    spacing: stl.setsCmnVertSpace

                    model: ListModel {
                        id: friendsModel
                    }

                    delegate: Widgets.FriendInfoWidget {
                        id: friendsInfoDelegate
                        mActive: model.isActive
                        isCoach: model.isCoach
                        mName: model.nickname
                        mID: model.ID
                        mIndex: (index + 1)
                    }
                    Component.onCompleted: refreshFriendsModel();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The issue was that I need to define "background" component of the delegate explicitly. In my case:

```
background: Rectangle {
  anchors.fill: friendDelegate
  color: "transparent"
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us what a Widgets.FriendInfoWidget is, but there is often a property exposed that allows you to change the background color without overriding the background item completely.